# Add 1 circle/rectangle after every input instead of all 20 at once in JS

Tags: javascript

I want my *program* to add 1 circle or rectangle depending on what user types in after every user input instead of all 20 at once in javascript, but I want 20 to be the max. I cant find any way to do it in my code, can anyone help me? What should I change, I'm new to JS. I managed to make it so that all of them are not overlapping when created, but can't find a way to make them 1 by 1. Every time a user writes 'circle' and presses submit 1 circle should appear same for rectangle, and every next time should additional 1 appear

```
var squares =[];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(420, 465);background('white');
  
  input = createInput();
  input.position(20, 65);

  button = createButton('submit');
  button.position(input.x + input.width, 65);
  button.mousePressed(greet);

  greeting = createElement('h2', 'circle or rectangle?');
  greeting.position(20, 5);

  textAlign(CENTER);
  textSize(50);
  
  function greet() {
  var name = input.value();
  if(name=='circle'){
    for(var i=0;i<20;i++){
    
    var circle = {
      x: random(30, 420),
      y: random (70, 465),
      r: random(5,50),
    };
    var overlapping=false;
    
    for(var j=0; j<circles.length;j++){
      var o=circles[j];
      var d= dist(circle.x,circle.y, o.x,o.y);
      
      if(d<circle.r+o.r){
        overlapping=true;
     break; } 
    }
    
    if(!overlapping){
    circles.push(circle);}
    
    for(var i=0; i<circles.length;i++){
      
      noStroke();
      fill(random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255),150);
      ellipse(circles[i].x,circles[i].y,circles[i].r*2);
    }
  }
    }
    else if(name=='rectangle'){
      for(var i=0;i<20;i++){
    
    var square = {
      x: random(30,420),
      y: random (70,465),
      x2: random(5,100),
      y2: random(5,100),
    };
    var overlapping2=false;
    
    for(var j=0; j<squares.length;j++){
      var o2=squares[j];
      var d2= dist(square.x,square.y, o2.x,o2.y);
      
      if(d2<square.x2+o2.x2){
        overlapping2=true;
     break; } 
      if(d2<square.y2+o2.y2){
        overlapping2=true;
     break; } 
    }    
    if(!overlapping2){
    squares.push(square);}
    
    for(var i=0; i<squares.length;i++){
      
      noStroke();
      fill(random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255),150);
      rect(squares[i].x,squares[i].y,squares[i].x2,squares[i].y2);
    }
  }     
    }
    else if(name=='reset'){
      const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }
    else{};
    
  input.value('');  
}
function draw() {
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you simply remove the `for(var i=0;i<20;i++){` loop that creates 20 circles / rectangles in your `greet` function? Whenever you run `greet` you instantly create 20 shapes, simply make only 1 shape and 'wait' for the user to press the button again to run `greet` a second time.

Answer (score 1):

As I see when user enters circle or triangle to input you are creating them in for loop which runs until it reaches 20 `for(var i=0;i<20;i++)`. You should remove the for loop and use function instead of it and inside function you can limit user inputs with counter for each input